# On the TRS-80 models I and III when is the directory track number written in the third byte of sector zero, and when in the second byte?

Tags: floppy-disk, operating-system, trs-80

Earlier I had found that many but not all TRS-80 Model I and Model III disks begin with the three bytes `00h FEh 11h`.

This is the beginning of the boot sector where the CPU interprets it as a `NOP` followed by a `CMP` that is then ignored. Its real purpose is to declare which track the directory track is on, which by default is `11h`, track 17.

But just now I've discovered that just about as many disks start the boot sector without the `NOP` and just with `FEh 11h`.

These TRS-80s had many DOS's from different companies which were mostly compatible. But sometimes there was a Model I version and a Model III version of the same DOS since the machines were not 100% compatible.

Do we know if certain DOS's used the `NOP` with the track number then on the third byte and other DOS's put the track number on the second byte with no `NOP`. Or do we know if this was a difference between Model 1 and 3 versions of the same DOS? Or something else?

Comment: Since you already found them, mind to add on what products did so? In addition, this looks quite like a duplicate to your own question (and [findings](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15001/6659))

Comment: @Raffzahn While very general questions that start from little knowledge are simply the nature of asking questions, these tend to generate smaller, more specific questions. It's perfectly reasonable (and even a good idea) to extract those generated questions into separate RCSE questions that can focus on the specific point. Once an appropriate answer to this question appears, the [original more general question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/15000/7208) and/or its answers can be edited to reference this one.